# Iterating through relationships from query result while adding new relationship of the same type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to add new relationship based on the transitive relationship of path length 2 between 2 nodes, all these relationships are of the same type (:TRUST). I am using the Java API and got something like below working, but it seems that the newly added relationship will appear in my result iterator eventually even though it didn't exist at the time of executing the query. Is there anyway that I can avoid it?

```
private final String FIND_TRANSITIVE_RELATION_QUERY =
        "MATCH (a:" + TwitterLabels.USERS + ") " +
                "- [ab:" + TwitterRelationships.TRUST + "] -> " +
                "(b:" + TwitterLabels.USERS + ") " +
                "- [bc:" + TwitterRelationships.TRUST + "] -> " +
                "(c:" + TwitterLabels.USERS + ")\n" +
                "WHERE a <> c\n" +
                "return ab, bc";

public void insertSimpleTransitiveTrust(){
    try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
    {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Result result = graphDb.execute( FIND_TRANSITIVE_RELATION_QUERY, params );

        while(result.hasNext()){
            Map<String, Object> map = result.next();
            Object object = map.get("ab");
            Relationship trustAb = (Relationship) object;
            object = map.get("bc");
            Relationship trustBc = (Relationship) object;

            Node nodeA = trustAb.getStartNode();
            Node nodeB = trustAb.getEndNode();
            Node nodeC = trustBc.getEndNode();

            Relationship transitiveTrust = nodeA.createRelationshipTo(nodeC, TwitterRelationships.TRUST);
            transitiveTrust.setProperty("transitiveTrust", trustBc.getPropety(TwitterProperties.CONVERSATIONAL_TRUST));

        }


        tx.success();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both, iteration and modification run within the same transaction. That's why your seeing your own modifications.

To prevent that execute the modifications in a another transaction in a different thread, see a code snippet from apoc procedures using that approach: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/periodic/Periodic.java#L230-L260

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would it be possible to briefly explain how I can use it in my case? Thanks.

Comment: Hi I tried using the code but it gives me NotInTransactionException. I read online that transaction is bounded to a thread, does creating the transaction in a singleThreadExecutor bounds it to a different thread that the consumer is in?